# Form and Request.Form in a asp.net MVC3 Facebook Application

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm working on a facebook app and facing a problem with my forms with MVC3 with Razor.

A. Working form:

index.cshtml

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("tbTest", "Pouet pouet", new { Width = "500px" })
            <input type="submit" name="btnCalculate">calculer vos tarifs</input>
        } Result form : @Request.Form <br />
```

HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

B. Bugging form :

About.cshtml :

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("tbTest", "Pouet pouet", new { Width = "500px" })
            <input type="submit" name="btnCalculate">calculer vos tarifs</input>
        } Result form : @Request.Form <br />
```

HomeController.cs :

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,manage_pages,offline_access")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
        FacebookWebClient fbApi = new FacebookWebClient(FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken);

        dynamic result = fb.Get("me");
        return View();
    }
```

In apps.facebook.com/appname/home/index, the form is working, Request.Form return tbTest = Pouet pouet.
In apps.facebook.com/appname/home/about, the form return nothing else but Signed_Request.

EDIT
If I edit HomeController.cs like this

```
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,manage_pages,offline_access")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
```

the first page, index.cshtml, does not work anymore... The post only return Signed_Request.

So, I think I have a problem using Facebook SDK and Signed request, no ?
Could you help me please. Why does the form is not sent or lost in the About page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for post backs you need to maintain the signed request manually.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/5364815/157260

Comment: Thank you. With Razor : <input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="@Request.Params["signed_request"]"/>

Answer (score 0):

Because you have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

in your About form, which causes it to POST to Index instead of About. Change it to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Sorry, i paste it without editing it as I had to. This is not the problem, my code is right, at least for that.

Comment: I think it looks like it's related to the Facebook SDK, and I am not familiar with that.